SN2 nucleophilic substitution reaction push and pull transition state
in 4 chloroquinazoline ring, if alphamethylbenzylamine reats with it, this is SN2 nucleophilic substitution reaction, so when the lone pairs of nitrogen attacks the carbon , in the pull and push transition state, the carbon here will have 5 bonds (3 bonds from the ring, 1 bond CL, and 1, bond of nitrogen) so here the carbon will carry partial positive charge and the CL and nitrogen will carry partial negative charge, but how as the nitrogen is carrying 2 hydrogen atoms so it will has at this moment 4 bonds so it should have partial positive charge, so what will it carry which charge and why? also can after that in this reaction the Cl atom react with a hydrogen atom from this amine to form HCl at the end of this reaction and how can this occur how the bond of the Proton could leave ?

You better familiarise yourself with correct use of capital letters and punctuation - more important than details of mechanisms.

4-Chloroquinazoline (1) has the polarized resonance structure shown in the red box. The partial negative charge is stabilized by resonance between $\ce{N1 and N3}$ while the partial positive charge is stabilized by the aromatic ring with a minor contribution from chlorine. Nucleophilic attack of the amine at $\ce{C1}$ provides intermediate 2, which undergoes tautomerization providing either structures 3 ($\ce{N1-protonation}$) and 4 ($\ce{N3-protonation}$) or both. Either red nitrogen in 3 may be utilized to eliminate chloride but only the α-phenethylamine nitrogen is shown forming 6, which is resonance stabilized by the electron pair on $\ce{N1}$. Deprotonation at $\ce{N1}$ produces the substitution product, amine 7. Alternatively, structure 4 may employ either red nitrogen to eliminate chloride. The use of $\ce{N3}$ is illustrated with the loss of a proton to form amine 7.
The number of bonds at each atom is correct. I would be reluctant to call this an $\ce{SN2}$ reaction but rather an addition/substitution reaction. To my understanding, $\ce{SN2}$ reactions occur at sp3 carbons, undergo inversion of stereochemistry and proceed through a transition state without intermediates. This reaction involves an sp2 center with no stereochemical inversion and with the formation of intermediates.   Incidently, to conduct this reaction properly, one uses at least two equivalents of α-phenethylamine to scavenge HCl. Typically, a less expensive amine, such as triethylamine, is utilized.


thanks a lot of this explanation this helped me a lot :) , i want to ask in figure 2 , the reaction proceed to 4 to continue to 5 and 7/ or proceeds to 3 to continue to 3 and 6 , which one will be preferred and why? ,, and is it right that in SN2 raction conversion of configuration occurs as i read this before is this right?

why tautomerism occurs here although tautomerism requires hydrogen to be attached to carbon and here the hyrdogen is attached to N ? also tautomerism requires acidic or basic catalyst that is not afforded here , so does amine acts as acidic  catalyst?

can also this drawing explanation be applied in 2,4 dichloroquinazoline?


Which one is preferred, 3 or 4. No idea. Does it matter?, 2) There is inversion of configuration in an SN2 rxn. but there is no SN2 here., 3) Tautomerization is not exclusive to carbon. In the broadest sense it means that some atom moves from one atom to another., 4) In intermediate 2, there is both an acid and a base., 5) 2,4 -dichloroquinazoline would be similar.


but why this is not sn2 reaction as it is a nucleophilic attack that attacks the carbon to push out he the chlorine atom and this reaction was done in non polar solvent so why? yes in Sn2 reactions there are no intermediates but these intermediates here can only be considered to be in the transition states right?

@NEMO It's not SN2 because it's SNAr.

Also if this is 2,4 dichloroquinazoline can you help me drawing the tautomerism that occurs when nucleophilic attack occurs at position 2 after being attacked at 4, as I tried but I stop in a certain point where I can't draw how the bonds will move?

And what forces deprotonation to occur
